# wordpress - Change page name when user is logged out

Tags: wordpress

I have a page named My account, I want when I log out to change the title of the page in "Log In / Register".

I tryed this code:

```
function wp_change_title( $title ) {
if ( !is_user_logged_in() && get_page_by_title( 'My Account' ) ) {
return 'Log In / Register';
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wp_change_title' );
```

But it changes the name to all the pages when I log out, how do I do to only change the name of the My account page?

Answer (score 1):

try `is_page('My Account')` instead of `get_page_by_title()`. get_page_by_title() [is a query, not a conditional](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title).